# Russian text is not being displayed properly

Tags: html, ios, iphone

I have an application that fetch the RSS feed of YouTube in that the **titles**  of the videos are coming in the russian language for example

Караоке для Детей 1

Now the problem is that this text is not being decoded properly and I am getting some garbage characters.

Please help, it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT : here is the code through which I am getting the string from the HTML content :

```
[NSString stringWithCString:&aXMLElement->text[0] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Thanks
Kuldeep

Comment: Probably an encoding issue, but you have to show more code. How do you read the data, how do you convert the data to strings for the text dispay ... ?

Comment: @MartinR I have edited the question with the piece of code. Please review it and let me know your comments

Comment: What does `aXMLElement->text` contain? What do you get as `NSString`?

Comment: @MartinR Suppose if we have tag <title>Караоке для Детей 1</title> in the HTML, then the aXMLElement->text will contain the value of that tag means "Караоке для Детей 1".